# Parsing solidity bytes to params

Tags: solidity

I have two functions on contract:

function 1 receives `bytes params` variable

`function foo1(bytes memory params)`

function 2 receives two params: `address param1, uint256 param2`

`function foo2(address param1, uint256 param2)`

my goals somehow pass params as bytes to `foo1`, decode it on function, and pass decoded params to `foo2`

like:

```
function foo2(address param1, uint256 param2) {
   // do something
}

function decode(bytes params) private returns(???){
  // decode
}

function foo1(bytes params) public {
  var decodedParams = fromBytes(params)
  foo2(decodedParams.param1, decodedParams.param2)
}
```

from frontend I expect something like:

```
  const params = toBytes({param1: '0xAddRess', param2: 1})

  myContract.foo1(params)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Solidity built-in function [abi.decode](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/units-and-global-variables.html#abi-encoding-and-decoding-functions) for this.

```
(address param1, uint256 param2) = abi.decode(params, (address, uint256));
```

For a real-world example, see how I use `abi.decode` in a flash swap contract that pulls liquidity from Uniswap V2: [HifiFlashUniswapV2](https://github.com/hifi-finance/hifi/blob/f02f7d4c2be8780353144c9cb65908b62f42591b/packages/flash-swap/contracts/uniswap-v2/HifiFlashUniswapV2.sol#L119).

Comment: exactly what I am looking for, thanks :)